# How to use Tensorflow GPU with CUDA 10 on RTX 2070?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, rtx

in a few days I will setup my new computer with a RTX 2070.
I would like to user tensorflow GPU but I can't find compatible versions of CUDA and Tensorflow GPU.
As far as I know, I need CUDA 10 to benefit from the additional computing power of the RTX's Turing architecture. But regarding to the Tensorflow website the newest version of tf (tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0) only works with CUDA 9.
I would prefer to get it all working on windows 10 but if there is no other way, linux would work as well.

Somewhere on the internet I read about two rumors:
1. there is some way to compile an unpublished version of tf-gpu which works with CUDA 10
2. they will publish an official version of tf-gpu in january 2019 (which is almost over now) which will support CUDA 10.

Can someone confirm one of those rumors (with source would be the best) or tell me how I will be able to get it all working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that you need cuda 10 and that tensorflow-gpu currently doesn't support it. What you need to do is compile tensorflow from source like your first rumor.

**Installation steps:**

1. Install CUDA 10 and cuDNN 7.3.1
2. Configure Tensorflow and compile it
3. Install the .whl package with pip

Here are some tutorials to compile tensorflow.

**Windows:**

> https://www.pytorials.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-10-0-for-python-on-windows/2/

**Ubuntu:**

> https://medium.com/@saitejadommeti/building-tensorflow-gpu-from-source-for-rtx-2080-96fed102fcca
>
> https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-tensorflow-work-on-rtx-20xx-series-73eb409bd3c0

**Alternatively** 
you can find the pre-built tensorflow wheels here, thus skipping step 2:

> https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel